# Creating a column based on pattern matching in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a date frame containing two columns 'Name' and 'Task'. I want to create a third column called 'task_category' based on matching condition from a list. Please note the below data is only for example and I actually have 100s of patterns to look for instead of the three shown below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'Name': ["a","b","c"],
        'Task': ['went to trip','Mall Visit','Cinema']})
task_category=['trip','Mall','Cinema']

    Name    Task        task_category
0   a   went to trip    trip
1   b   Mall Visit      Mall
2   c   Cinema          Cinema
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using find all , since this will help you finding same key words in same line

```
df.Task.str.findall('|'.join(task_category)).str[0]
Out[1008]: 
0      trip
1      Mall
2    Cinema
Name: Task, dtype: object
```

---

Sample

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Name': ["a","b","c"],
    'Task': ['went to trip Cinema','Mall Visit','Cinema']})

df.Task.str.findall('|'.join(task_category))
Out[1012]: 
0    [trip, Cinema]
1            [Mall]
2          [Cinema]
Name: Task, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`series.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
pat=r'({})'.format('|'.join(task_category))
#'(trip|Mall|Cinema)'
df['task_category']=df.Task.str.extract(pat)
print(df)
```

---

```
  Name          Task task_category
0    a  went to trip          trip
1    b    Mall Visit          Mall
2    c        Cinema        Cinema
```

Comment: @anky_91 - Ya, not with sample data, but with general duplicated data - values matched condition.

Comment: Both the answers are great. I am accepting the one by Wen-Ben.

Comment: @itthrill absolutely, no problem. :) Whatever you find best. Cheers..!!